# My python code does not return a page? Concerns HTML Forms

Tags: python

for a school project, I am required to build a page using forms. However, my code does not return a page. Instead, it only returns my code in .txt form. I'm not sure why this is the problem. Is this the python code that I wrote is wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html"
print

#May 17
import cgi, cgitb
cgitb.enable()

form=cgi.FieldStorage()

#May19
dataset1=open('Book1.csv','r')
dataset2=open('Race Demographic by state.txt','r')

sources='''<hr><h4>Sources!</h4><a     href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_the_United_States">Race Demographics</a>
<a href="http://voices.yahoo.com/average-sat-scores-state-2010-7702520.html?cat=4">SAT     Scores</a>
<a href="http://lisa.stuy.edu/~keiran.carpen/BriansDirectory/Sat scores by     state.txt">SAT Scores txt file</a>
<a href="http://lisa.stuy.edu/~keiran.carpen/BriansDirectory/Race Demographic by     state.txt">Race Demographics txt file</a></body></html>'''

def datasplitter(x):
    data = x.read()
    return data.split("\n")


def datdatamang(x):
    data = datasplitter(x)
    index = 0
    WhileNumber = 0
    while index < len(data):
        WhileNumber = 0
        string = data[index]
        string.split(" ")
        x=''
        while WhileNumber < len(string):
            if string[WhileNumber] == ',':
                x=x+'</td><td>'
            else:
                x=x+string[WhileNumber]
            WhileNumber+= 1
        ' '.join(string)
        data[index]='<tr><td>'+x+'</td></tr>'
        index+=1
    result=' '.join(data)
    result='''<table border='1'>'''+result+'</table>'
    return result
#May 19
def getDescription():
    page = ''
#May20
    if 'Submit' in form:
        if "Description" in form:
            page+= 'Ever since its conception, the SAT examinations have been widely     controversial.Many individuals believe that their race is the most intellectually superior,     and that their SAT scores reflect on their superiority. It is my job to find this     correlation between scores and race and end the battle among the races!'
        if "High SAT Scores" in form:
            page+= datdatamang('Book1.csv')
        if "Race Demographics" in form:
            page+= datdatamang('Race Demographics by state.txt')
        if "source" in form:
            page+= sources
#May 19

#May 20
print '''<!doctype html><title>SAT Analysis</title>'''
print '''<body>'''+getDescription()+'''</body></html>'''



#May 17 - Writing the analysisV2.html file and starting the code
#May 19 - Tables, and the like
#May 20 - Writing if statements, building the page.
```

Comment: What kind of web server are you running this on?  Is it configured to treat Python scripts as CGI programs?  Does the program need a `.cgi` extension and/or to be made executable?

Comment: Have you set up your web server to execute CGI scripts?

Comment: D'oh. I forgot to run this on my web-server. Let me try this out right now to see if it works.

Comment: I'm still having trouble running this on my web-server, as it just prints out the .txt version of my code when I submit the HTML form.

Comment: This is the link to the web-server app that I am using:
[link](http://69.55.54.194/pbrooks/spring2012_old/materials/ml2/python_web_server_installation.html)

Comment: I cannot reach that link.

Comment: @MartijnPieters http://69.55.54.194/pbrooks/spring2012_old/materials/ml2/python_web_server_installation.html

Comment: @BrianLee: exactly, I am not allowed to contact that IP address. That is an internal server to your educational institute.